# Create redirect link based on current user using java & html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

Authentication based on Google account.

How to create redirect link based on current user.
For example: My site: *www.test.com/home*

- If user A logged on, when he/she press my page it should go to `www.test.com/User A`
- If user B logged on, when he/she press my page it should go to  `www.test.com/user B`

Note: PHP not support in my application

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$user=$_POST['user'];
Header("Location: www.test.com/".$user);
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple redirection based on $user var:

```
Header("Location: http://mypage.com/".$user);
```

Comment: Thnaks, In google sites i have only html and app script option. I'm not sure about php. Is there possible to through HTML.

Comment: @user3766722 Yes, you can use a meta redirect. <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" /> It's going to be tough getting the username in though.

Comment: Consider to use Google App Engine instead of Google Sites https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine?csw=1

Comment: @Peter I agree, but u mentioned example was not supporting to redirect based on user. Please help

Comment: It isn't possible to achieve what you want in plain HTML - I don't have knowledge about how you authenticate your users but I'm pretty sure it cannot be done using only HTML. That's why I suggested to use Google App Engine because it supports php

Comment: @violator667 Okay and im very new for google sites and google app. Thanks anyway, i ll try my best